# Is it mandatory to include royalties inside smart contract code of an NFT smart contract?

Tags: nft, erc-721, erc-1155, royalties, erc

I have created a smart contract for the NFT collection marketplace and did not include any royalties inside the smart contract.
I would like to confirm whether do I need to add some functions inside the smart contract for getting royalties or do I need to manage with the NFT platform externally without including it in the smart contract code?

Comment: Not mandatory. Check out [EIP-2981: NFT Royalty Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not mandatory.

The mandatory things are specified in [ERC-721 specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721)

Answer (score 2):

Most likely royalties are handled by the marketplace. If the required the NFT contract to include some royalty functionality, they would have very few NFTs to sell.

The NFT (ERC-721) standard doesn't have any notion of royalties. Check out EIP-2981 standard [EIP-2981: NFT Royalty Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-2981)